# "Полкать" - этимология

Tags: этимология

В Сибири, есть в ходу такой глагол `полкать` (ударение на второй слог). Встречается до сих пор на Алтае, Кемерово и Новосибирской области. Означает *шататься, слоняться*, иногда применяется в значении *искать*

> я все обполкал, но не нашел

Есть у кого-то идеи по-поводу этимологии этого странного глагола/слова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=100575  
Да, это регионально разговорное слово.
Значение: беспорядочно или быстро двигаться, мотаться, носиться; идти или ехать далеко.

Регион: Западная Сибирь (Курганская обл., Тюменская обл., Омская обл., Томская обл., Новосибирская обл., Кемеровская обл., Алтайский край); Северный Казахстан (Усть-Каменогорск); Красноярский край, Тува.

http://my-dictionary.ru/word/62589/polkat/       
По Далю, ПОЛКАТЬ (сиб.) - шататься, слоняться, таскаться, рыскать туда и сюда, бездельничая. Он только полкает, праздно слоняется (не от этого ль полк, начально: бродячая толпа, ватага?).

Вполне разумное объяснение у Даля - полкать - шататься по улицам  полком, т.е. толпой, бродить в поисках развлечений или чего-то материального.

Answer (score 2):

> Есть у кого-то идеи по поводу
>   этимологии этого странного
>   глагола/слова?

Единственное, что нашёл:

> праслав. *pъlkati (рус. диал. полкать
>   "шататься, слоняться"), чеш. диал.
>   plkati "болтать") возводится к гнезду
>   *pel- "махать, колебать"...

См. https://books.google.ru/books?id=pRlZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%22+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%22+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=G0YtVeb4Osa2swHIj4PABA&redir_esc=y

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Полкан - кому кентавр, а кому - псина, пёс, способный к поисковой работе.

Comment: Было бы - "полканить".

Comment: А есть же выражение *полкАнить* - то есть выискивать, попрошайничать. Вполне себе версия. Скорее всего *полкать* и *полканить* однокоренные слова.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, мнение о том, что слово происходит от "полк"(либо полкА, слово, так же связанное с группой людей), верно, ну у меня несколько иная точка зрения на этот счёт. Есть такое понятие - **поле половецкое** , так вот, **половцы**, как кочевой народ, вполне могли **полкать**, то есть: шататься, искать-рыскать, слонятся. А полки ходили строем.

Comment: Дело в том, что с половцами связана тема набегов,военной агрессии и всё такое подобное, а этот глагол относится к экспрессивным глаголам с архисемой 'работать/не работать' в говорах территории ПОЗДНЕГО заселения в числе подобных:блукать,бродяжить, колобродить,мотыляться,шлындать, шляться - т.е. бездельничать и шататься без дела группой

Comment: Значит, всё-таки от "полкА"(с ударением на "а") - ватага, компания, но никак не от "полк".

Answer (score 0):

У нас в Туве *полкать* означает быстро и широко искать или быстро куда-либо сходить.

Answer (score -1):

Попробовал поискать по ИРИС-словарю путём подбора букв , - [ИРИС-словарь](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php) . Нашёл два письменных совпадения . **1**. **פולח** //   по-буквенно *пей*-*вав*-*ламед*-*хет*  или П-О-Л-Х , означает "*разрезающий* , *рассекающий* , *проникать*(*лит.*)"   **2**. **פולה** // по-буквенно *пей*-*вав*-*ламед*-*хей*  или П-О-Л-Х , означает "*бить вшей*" . Примечание : *пей* это П / Ф ; *вав* это В / У (как W) или О ; *ламед* это Л ; *хет* это Х гортанный ; *хей* это Х заглатываемый . *Внимание : иврит пишется справа-налево* ! С учётом специфики иврита оба слова можно прочитать , как **ПОЛХ** .  Х легко перейдёт в К , - подобных примеров достаточно .                       [image: ПОЛХ-1]                                           [image: ПОЛХ-2]===========================================================================                                                                                 Ну , а если брать по смыслу , то , может ,  в переносном значении подойдёт второе : типа БИТЬ ВШЕЙ это , как БИТЬ БАКЛУШИ , тоже , что ШАТАТЬСЯ , СЛОНЯТЬСЯ (в смысле - бездельничать) . Кроме того , БИТЬ ВШЕЙ можно понимать и , как ВЫИСКИВАТЬ ВШЕЙ , то есть , что-то ВЫИСКИВАТЬ . **Ивритная версия - тоже версия , хотя полной убеждённости я высказать не решаюсь .**